# CSS Align Divs Correctly

Tags: html, css

So I have these two big divs, I want one to be the mainbar, and one to be a sidebar to the right. I've tried making them both float to the left, also tried using width percentages but I couldn't figure it out. Maybe you guys can?
This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container box" style="clear:both !important;">
</div>
<div class="sidebar sidebarbox" style="clear:both !important;">
</div>
```

Then this is the CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: rgba(224, 222, 217, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-top:25px;
}
.container {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
width: 60%;
padding: 20px;
background-color: none;
border: 1px solid #C9C7C8;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
min-height: 450px;
}
.sidebar {
float: left;
width: 20%;
padding: 20px;
background-color: none;
border: 1px solid #C9C7C8;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right:10px;
min-height: 450px;
}
.boxsidebar {
    background-color: rgba(224, 222, 217, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Is anybody able to figure this out? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you post [JSFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Linek http://jsfiddle.net/EeAaB/345/

Comment: What do you mean by "mainbar"? Container for page content?

Answer (score 0):

You have inline styling (set to important) which is overriding the float.

Set your html to:

```
<div class="container box">
</div>
<div class="sidebar sidebarbox">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Your code could be cleaned up a bit.. but the above will solve your issue of the boxes not floating next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want box to be main content container, and sidebar to be to the right of box element.

All you need is this:

HTML

```
<div class="container box">
</div>
<div class="sidebar sidebarbox">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
background-color: rgba(224, 222, 217, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.container {
float: left;
width: 60%;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #C9C7C8;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
min-height: 450px;
}
.sidebar {
float: left;
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid #C9C7C8;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
min-height: 450px;
}
.boxsidebar {
background-color: rgba(224, 222, 217, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1a1a18;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

You can further clean this code by creating general classes that add shadowbox, that way your selectors are not as cluttered.

Hope this helps.